# Where were Saul & Mira at the end of Season 3?

Tags: film-location, homeland

Near the close of the last episode of series 3 of homeland we see Saul & Mira relaxing on the rooftop of a sun-kissed building; but where are they?

I think I remember in a different episode Saul saying he wanted to go live/retire some where, but I cant recall, and perhaps it isn't the same place anyway.

Any body know where they are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's actually Asilah, Morocco.

It says it was filmed there but depicts Greece. You can see photos from the link below.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=376513599150057&set=a.376512982483452.1073741828.145172285617524&type=3&theater

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.376512982483452.1073741828.145172285617524&type=3